# Super Search range not working

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I've purchased Solspace's Super Search but can't seem to get the range working correctly. I've followed the docs and it seems to be set-up correctly but isn't correctly returning the ranges.

I'm using a simple GET filter form for a size range. The sizes are inputted into EE and are being collated correctly in the form but the results aren't working.

This is my form:

```
<form action="{path='letting/search'}" id="letting_form" method="GET">
        <label>Search by size:</label> 
        <select class="small" style="margin-right:6px;" name="unitsize-from"> 
            <option value="0">From</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="150">150</option>
            <option value="250">250</option>
            <option value="350">350</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
        </select>

        <select class="small" name="unitsize-to">
            <option value="9999">To</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="150">150</option>
            <option value="250">250</option>
            <option value="350">350</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="750">750</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
        </select>

        <select name="unit_type">
            <option value="">Select Retail or Office Availability</option>
            <option value="retail_space">Retail Space</option>
            <option value="office_space">Office Space</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

It outputs:

```
/search?unitsize-from=250&unitsize-to=750&unit_type=retail_space
```

This is my output:

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="unit_space"}
    {if unit_availability == "Available"}
    <tr>
        <td>{unit_type}</td>
        <td>{categories}{category_name}{/categories}</td>
        <td>{title}</td>
        <td>{unitsize}</td>
        <td><a href="{unit_brochure}">Download</a></td>
        <td><a class="view-more" href="#{url_title}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    {if:else}
    <p>There are no units available at this time.</p>
    {/if}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super Search works best as a POST form. Try changing your form to have `method="POST"`.

Also, if you haven't done so yet, you might also want to go in the Super Search CP, under the **Fields** tab, and change the field type to an integer to allow better -from/-to range searches based on numbers. Make a backup of your database before you do any changes there.

Comment: Thanks! The field type fix worked. Anyone else having this issue, just make sure the field type is set to integer.